# Factory / Service in essence

Tags: angularjs, factory, angularjs-service, angular-services

I’m trying to understand what the essential differences between service and factory are (in AngularJS). Is it true to say that a factory is a singleton and a service is a new object every time you call it?

Comment: No. A factory is a function that is used to construct a service. A service is always a singleton. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angular-js-service-vs-provider-vs-factory/15666049#15666049

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, functions can resemble a class which has instance variables, instance methods, and can be new'ed up:

```
// creating a class Box
function Box(col)
{
   // instance member variable color, default to 'Red' if no color passed
   var color = col || 'Red';

   // instance method
   this.getColor = function()
   {
      return color;
   }
}
```

To instantiate a Box, and initialize it with different colors:

```
var blueBox = new Box("blue");
alert(blueBox.getColor()); // will alert blue

var greenBox = new Box("green");
alert(greenBox.getColor()); // will alert green
```

An angular service is used to register constructor functions like the Box example.  When the service is injected, an instance of the service is passed into your function:

```
// declare a service
app.service('box', Box);

// inject instance of Box into controller: 'box' is a new Box()
app.controller('ctrl', function(box) {
    alert(box.getColor()); // alerts  'Red'
});
```

In contrast, an angular factory does not return an instance of a function. Instead, it caches and returns the result of invoking the function:

```
// declare a factory
app.factory('user', function() {

    // return an object literal
    return  {
        name: 'john',
    }
});


app.controller('ctrl', function(user) {
   alert(user.name);// user is the object literal which was returned from the user factory.
};
```

Think of factories as a way of returning the result of a function; the result is a singleton an shared between all injections.

Think of services as a way of instantiating classes (or function constructors); the instance is also a singleton and shared between all injections.

Both factories and services are singletons.

Comment: I quote `a service follows a factory method design pattern (a new function instance is created with every injection).` : NO . services and factories are both singletons.Services dont create new instances on each injection.

Answer (score 1):

the only difference between services and factories is that services are called with new

```
stuffToInject = new Service();
```

whereas factories are just called like functions

```
stuffToInject = Factory();
```

Otherwise it's the same,both Factories and Services are singleton.The only question you need to ask yourself is does my Service needs the new operator or not.If not ,use `module.factory`,else `module.service`.

exemple:

```
function(){
  this.foo=function(){
  }
}
```

**needs** to be registered with module.service

```
function(){
   return {
    foo:function(){}
   };
}
```

**can** be registered with  module.factory